# Got error message "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains" During Login with Facebook C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am trying to connect with Facebook API to authorize access to get profile data for Login process,
Here is my code:

```
string facebook_urlAuthorize_base = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize";
string facebook_urlGetToken_base = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
string facebook_AppID = "APPID";
string facebook_AppSecret = "APPSECERET";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request["code"] != null)
        {
          
            string authorizationCode = Request["code"];
            string access_token = Facebook_GetAccessToken(authorizationCode);
            if (access_token == "")
            {
                Response.Write("Could not get access_token");
                return;
            }
       
        }
    }


}
protected void Login(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Facebook_AuthorizeApplication();
}


private void Facebook_AuthorizeApplication()
{ 
    string scope = "name,email"; 
    string urlAuthorize = facebook_urlAuthorize_base;
    urlAuthorize += "?client_id=" + facebook_AppID;
    urlAuthorize += "&redirect_uri=" + Facebook_GetRedirectUri();
    urlAuthorize += "&scope=" + scope;

    Response.Redirect(urlAuthorize, true); 
}



private string Facebook_GetAccessToken(string pAuthorizationCode)
{
    
    string urlGetAccessToken = facebook_urlGetToken_base;
    urlGetAccessToken += "?client_id=" + facebook_AppID;
    urlGetAccessToken += "&client_secret=" + facebook_AppSecret;
    urlGetAccessToken += "&redirect_uri=" + Facebook_GetRedirectUri();
    urlGetAccessToken += "&code=" + pAuthorizationCode;
    string responseData = RequestResponse(urlGetAccessToken);
    if (responseData == "")
    {
        return "";
    }
    NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(responseData);
    string access_token = qs["access_token"] == null ? "" : qs["access_token"];
    return access_token;
    
}
```

Get an error message response from Facebook:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 191,
        "fbtrace_id": "A5K3mmpL-3LosCnW4b6Nv_9"
    }
}
```

I am calling the API from http://localhost:13193/user/Default.aspx
I tried to modify the the app setting in dashboard Facebook developers page:
Site URL: http://localhost:13193/user/
App Domain: localhost
I set the privacy policy URL as well using Generate Privacy Policy website.

What am I doing wrong, Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

I switched to JavaScript SDK for Facebook and I got Successed connecting to Facebook and I got token only once, when I retried to access token it returns empty.

```
      <div class="fb-login-button" onclick="checkLoginState()"  

scope="public_profile,email">Login with Facebook</div>
                  <!--   <asp:HiddenField  runat="server" /> --> 
               <div id ="FBToken"></div>




           window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
               FB.init({
                   appId: '501435960911890',
                   cookie: true,
                   xfbml: true,
                   version: 'v10.0'
               });

               FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

           };

           (function (d, s, id) {
               var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
               if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
               js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
               js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
               fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
           }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

           function checkLoginState() {


               FB.login(function (response) {
                   if (response.authResponse) {
                       alert('You are logged in & cookie set!');
     
                   } else {
                       alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                   }
               });





               FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                   // $("#Facebook_Token").value = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);
                   $("#FBToken").html("<code>" + JSON.stringify(response, null, 2) + "</code>")
               });
           }
```

Comment: What is the exact value the `redirect_uri` parameter has in the login dialog URL you are redirecting to?  That one needs to be set in your app settings for Valid OAuth Redirect URIs. Did you specify the app domain as well, and configure the Website platform?

Comment: Yes I did all of that and it has been Successed for JavaScript SDK only once :(

Comment: These are asynchronous methods, so calling `FB.login` and then `FB.getLoginStatus` directly after, makes little sense to begin with.